# List installed packages only from disk image

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

My Raspberry running Raspbian crashed but I would like to know which packages I had installed on that SD card. Is there a way to detect that without actually booting the system?

Comment: In general, you can mount the disk in a similar system, chroot into it, and run `dpkg -l`. This is a general method. I don't know if it would work for Raspbian, but I don't see why not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debian's package databases are under `/var/lib/dpkg`. They're text files, fairly easy to parse manually even if you don't have Debian tools around. In particular, the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` contains one paragraph of information for every package (not just installed packages but also some other packages known to the system), starting with `Package: PACKAGENAME`.

```
cd /media/sdcard0/var/lib/dpkg
<status awk -v RS= '/\nStatus: install ok installed\n/ {print $2}'
```

If you aren't on unix or other system with `awk` or other text processing tool, you can inspect the directory `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. Every package except for virtual dependency-only packages has several files there, including at least `PACKAGENAME.list`.

If you're on a system with `dpkg`, you can tell it to consult a database other than the normal one.

```
dpkg --admindir=/media/sdcard0/var/lib/dpkg -l
dpkg --root=/media/sdcard0 -l
```

Comment: excellent, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: yes, very helpful! I learned tonight my old raspbian image from bananapi.org had only 20MiB allocated on /boot. It ran out of space mid bpi-update and won't boot now. I have to re-install from scratch after backing up the old card